# Dynamic override of ToString() using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, overriding, tostring

I generally override the ToString() method to output the property names and the values associated to them. I got a bit tired of writing these by hand so I'm looking for a dynamic solution.

Main:

```
TestingClass tc = new TestingClass()
{
    Prop1 = "blah1",
    Prop2 = "blah2"
};
Console.WriteLine(tc.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

TestingClass:

```
public class TestingClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }//properties
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public void Method1(string a) { }//method
    public TestingClass() { }//const
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Type type in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
        {
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
            {
                sb.Append(property.Name);
                sb.Append(": ");
                sb.Append(this.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).Name);
                sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

This currently outputs:

```
Prop1: System.String Prop1
Prop2: System.String Prop2
```

Desired Output:

```
Prop1: blah1
Prop2: blah2
```

I'm open for other solutions, it doesn't have to use reflection, it just has to produce the desired output.

Comment: You need to use the `GetValue` method.

Comment: You should not use `ToString` to return all property values in general. Instead you could provide a method `GetPropertyInfo` that does it if you want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public class TestingClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }//properties
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public void Method1(string a) { }//method
    public TestingClass() { }//const
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            sb.Append(property.Name);
            sb.Append(": ");
            if (property.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)
            {
                sb.Append("Indexed Property cannot be used");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(property.GetValue(this, null));
            }

            sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

To make it available everywhere you can create an Extension.
It's not possible to override methods in an Extension, but still it should simplify your life.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ToStringExtension(this object obj)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {

            sb.Append(property.Name);
            sb.Append(": ");
            if (property.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)
            {
                sb.Append("Indexed Property cannot be used");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(property.GetValue(obj, null));
            }

            sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can then call `ToStringExtension()` on every object.
Downside is, it doesn't work perfectly for lists etc., example:

```
var list = new List<string>();
// (filling list ommitted)
list.ToStringExtension();
// output:
// Capacity: 16
// Count: 11
// Item: Indexed Property cannot be used
```

Comment: What's about perfomance using reflection? What's about Hanselman implementation http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASmarterOrPureEvilToStringWithExtensionMethods.aspx ?

Comment: Working too for Nullable Properties **public int? Prop2 { get; set; }** or **public DateTime? Prop3 { get; set; }** ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an extension which will report the standard types such as string, int and Datetime but will also report string lists (shown below in `AccessPoints` which the above answer could not handle). Note that the output is aligned such as:

```
Name         : Omegaman
ID           : 1
Role         : Admin
AccessPoints : Alpha, Beta, Gamma
WeekDays     : Mon, Tue
StartDate    : 3/18/2014 12:16:07 PM
```

Below is the extension which takes in any type as long as its a class. It then reflects off of the public and private properties and if they are not null reports them.

```
public static string ReportAllProperties<T>(this T instance) where T : class
{

    if (instance == null)
        return string.Empty;

    var strListType = typeof(List<string>);
    var strArrType  = typeof(string[]);

    var arrayTypes   = new[] { strListType, strArrType };
    var handledTypes = new[] { typeof(Int32), typeof(String), typeof(bool), typeof(DateTime), typeof(double), typeof(decimal), strListType, strArrType };

    var validProperties = instance.GetType()
                                  .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                                  .Where(prop => handledTypes.Contains(prop.PropertyType))
                                  .Where(prop => prop.GetValue(instance, null) != null)
                                  .ToList();

    var format = string.Format("{{0,-{0}}} : {{1}}", validProperties.Max(prp => prp.Name.Length));

    return string.Join(
             Environment.NewLine,
             validProperties.Select(prop => string.Format(format, 
                                                          prop.Name,
                                                          (arrayTypes.Contains(prop.PropertyType) ? string.Join(", ", (IEnumerable<string>)prop.GetValue(instance, null))
                                                                                                  : prop.GetValue(instance, null)))));
}
```

### Usage

`myInstance.ReportAllProperties()`

Note that this is based off my blog article [C#: ToString To Report all Properties Even Private Ones Via Reflection](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1063) which provides a more robust explanation of what is going on.

Comment: Working too for Nullable Properties **public int? Prop2 { get; set; }** or **public DateTime? Prop3 { get; set; }** ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use JSON, Serializer will do all the hard work for you:

```cs
    public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static string ToStringEx(this object obj)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found, that works with most compicated-types (including List):

```
public static string ToXml(object Obj, System.Type ObjType)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer ser;
        XmlSerializerNamespaces SerializeObject = new mlSerializerNamespaces();
        ser = new XmlSerializer((ObjType));
        MemoryStream memStream;
        memStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlTextWriter xmlWriter;
        xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        xmlWriter.Namespaces = true;
        XmlQualifiedName[] qualiArrayXML = SerializeObject.ToArray();
        ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, Obj);
        xmlWriter.Close();
        memStream.Close();
        string xml;
        xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memStream.GetBuffer());
        xml = xml.Substring(xml.IndexOf(Convert.ToChar(60)));
        xml = xml.Substring(0, (xml.LastIndexOf(Convert.ToChar(62)) + 1));
        return xml;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { return string.Empty; }
}
```

usage:

```
string classAasString = ClassToXml.ToXml(a, typeof(ClassA)); //whare ClassA is an object
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself where I am looking for an option to serialize into something readable. If there are no read only properties xml serialization can give a readable string. However if there are read only properties / fields then xml serialization is not an option.

```
    public static string ToString(object serializeable)
    {
        var type = serializeable.GetType();
        try
        {
            var sw = new StringWriter();
            new XmlSerializer(type).Serialize(sw, serializeable);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            return type.FullName;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote an extension method that calls a library that has already figured out all the voodoo.

"override string ToString()" vs (my) "ToStringDump"....

Before I show the code, the reason I like the extension method (ToStringDump in this case).. better, is that I don't have to riddle my POCO/DTO objects with ObjectDump references.  I believe POCOs and DTOs should be "very very clean", and even isolated in their own assembly.  This way, these poco/dto objects are easily shared.

```
public static class ObjectDumpAdapter
{
    public static string ToStringDump(this object obj)
    {
        string returnValue = ObjectDumper.Dump(obj);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

My dotnet core csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ObjectDumper.NET" Version="2.5.20033.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Nuget link:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectDumper.NET/

---

Quote:

> ObjectDumper is a utility which aims to serialize C# objects to string
>   for debugging and logging purposes.

(from https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/ObjectDumper.NET )

---

GitHub link:

https://github.com/thomasgalliker/ObjectDumper